# Swiftui Async image not loading when frame size is below 500

Tags: swiftui

Been banging my head against the wall for weeks now! This code returns a gray square, but if I change the frame size to width 500, height 500 then it works. This doesn't make any sense, I can't reproduce the error.

Any frame size below 500 will show a grey background and no image, been deleting and starting from scratch multiple times, it must be a bug?

```
Section {
    VStack {
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: picture.downloadUrl)) { image in
        image
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
        } placeholder: {
            Color.gray.opacity(0.1)
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .cornerRadius(6)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the `.frame()` on the returned image itself?

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: picture.downloadUrl)) { image in
    image
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    } placeholder: {
        Color.gray.opacity(0.1)
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that didn't do it :/ I use the same code multiple places in my project, only here that it doesn't work

Comment: Should have shown you some more code, apparently the VStack did something that wouldn't display the image

Comment: [Minimal, Reproducible Examples (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rein everyone's best interests. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the VStack did the trick

Comment: works well for me with (or without) the `VStack` and with (or without) the `Section`. On macos 12.3, using XCode 13.3, targets ios 15 mac Catalyst 12.